# No FindVTK module in CMake

Tags: cmake, vtk

When I am trying to compile an open-source package which uses VTK, I get this error in CMake:

```
 include could not find load file:
/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindVTK.cmake
```

I looked in the path mentioned and there is indeed no `FindVTK` module. I think I compiled `VTK` successfully on the same machine, but now I have my doubts.

Isn't the `FindVTK.cmake` module meant to ship with CMake?

Is this module meant to appear after compilation of `VTk` source code?

Comment: ***Isn't the FindVTK.cmake module meant to ship with CMake?*** I do not have one with CMake-3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FindVTK.cmake was removed in CMake 3.1. It exists in versions prior to CMake 3.1.

[FindVTK.cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/module/FindVTK.html)

Answer (score 2):

The CMake documentation is pretty clear on this

> FindVTK 
>   This module no longer exists.
>
> This module existed in versions of CMake prior to 3.1, but became only
>   a thin wrapper around find_package(VTK NO_MODULE) to provide
>   compatibility for projects using long-outdated conventions. Now
>   find_package(VTK) will search for VTKConfig.cmake directly.

Source: 
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/module/FindVTK.html